# Using 'this' as a generic argument, conversion issues

Tags: c#, generics

Is this possible?  When i compile i get an error saying cannot convert Component to TComponent even with the constraint

```
public interface IComponent<TKey, TComponent> where TComponent : IComponent<TKey, TComponent>
{
    TComponent Parent { get; }
    void Register(TKey key, TComponent component);
    void RegsiterWith(TKey key, TComponent component);
}

public class Component<TKey, TComponent> : IComponent<TKey, TComponent> where TComponent : IComponent<TKey, TComponent>
{
    private TComponent _parent;

    public void Register(TKey key, TComponent component)
    {
        component.RegsiterWith(key, this);
    }

    public void RegsiterWith(TKey key, TComponent component)
    {
        component.Register(key, this);
    }

    public TComponent Parent { get { return _parent; } }
}
```

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but why is *component* param unused in Register and RegisterWith?

Comment: spender2, just changed it, thanks, is there a way without the cast? or will i have to wait for .net 4.0?

Comment: Hmm. I had another issue like this that looked like it had to wait til 4.0, then Marc Gravell solved it in a jiffy. So I dare not say it's an unsolvable co/contravariance issue because I'll probably be wrong!

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop if `component` is another instance of your `Component` class? I don't see anything preventing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that it fails is because `TComponent` could actually be some *other* implementation of `IComponent<TKey, TComponent>`. Just because `Component` implements the interface doesn't mean that nothing else can :)

One way round this would be to change the interface:

```
public interface IComponent<TKey, TComponent> 
    where TComponent : IComponent<TKey, TComponent>
{
    TComponent Parent { get; }
    void Register(TKey key, IComponent<TKey, TComponent> component);
    void RegsiterWith(TKey key, IComponent<TKey, TComponent> component);
}
```

Whether that's feasible in your situation I don't know, but it would certainly avoid the type issue.

Another option would be to cast `this` as spender suggested. This could fail at execution time, but in reality unless you *do* create an alternative implementation, it won't. It's slightly annoying, having to cast when using generics, but occasionally it happens.

EDIT: Here's an example of how it could go wrong:

```
public class Other : IComponent<string, Other>
{
    // Implement interface
}
```

Now what happens if you create a `Component<string, Other>`? It satisfies the constraint with no problems... but a `Component` isn't an `Other`...

Now you *could* change your constraint like this:

```
public class Component<TKey, TComponent> : IComponent<TKey, TComponent> 
    where TComponent : Component<TKey, TComponent>
```

i.e. constrain `TComponent` on `Component` instead of `IComponent`. That still has issues though:

```
public class FooComponent : Component<string, FooComponent> {}
public class BarComponent : Component<string, FooComponent> {}
```

Here, you probably want `BarComponent` to have a `TComponent` of itself, but it's got a different component. The code you've shown so far will probably be okay, but this sort of quirk may hamper other goals. Worth considering...

Oh, and if you're happy to make `Component` sealed, at that point the changed constraint *is* enough (I think!).

Comment: I don't get it, why should it matter whether or not TComponent could actually be some other implementation of IComponent<TKey, TComponent> as long as it implements "IComponent<TKey, TComponent>" it satisfies the constraint, shouldn't that in itself be sufficient for the compiler?

Comment: No - because "this" might not be a `TComponent`, but the second parameter of `Register`/`RegisterWith` *is* a `TComponent` in the original code. So it's got to convert "`this`" to `TComponent`... but "`this`" might not *be* a `TComponent`.

Comment: When you say "might not be", I don't see how that would be, given that the class for "this" IS A IComponent<TKey,IComponent>. In what scenario would this not be a TComponent. A concrete example may be helpful in understanding this.

Comment: Ahh... I see the problem now., that was tricky. Thx for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

How about a cast:

```
public void Register(TKey key, TComponent component)
{
    component.RegsiterWith(key, (TComponent)this);
}
```